# Listener is Null

Tags: android, listener

I am 100% sure onAttach method is called before onCreate, so **how my listener is null?** How can I fix that? Basically, if I can get the values from the NameDialog, I will call the another activity(let's say game) that implements NameDialogListener interface, so I will be able to override getTexts methods in the game activity.

```
    public class NameDialog extends AppCompatDialogFragment {
    private EditText firstPlayer;
    private EditText secondPlayer;
    private NameDialogListener listener;


    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_dialog, null);

        firstPlayer = view.findViewById(R.id.edit_player1);
        secondPlayer = view.findViewById(R.id.edit_player2);

        builder.setView(view)
                .setTitle("Names")
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    }
                })
                .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        String player1 = firstPlayer.getText().toString();
                        String player2 = secondPlayer.getText().toString();
                        listener.getTexts(player1, player2);
                        // Intent intent = new Intent(NameDialog.this.getActivity(), Game.class);
                        // startActivity(intent);


                    }
                });

        return builder.create();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        try {
           listener = (NameDialogListener) context;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public interface NameDialogListener {
        void getTexts(String player1, String player2);
    }
}
```

**ERROR - LOG:**

```
/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.anil.tictactoe, PID: 6009
                  **java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.example.anil.tictactoe.NameDialog$NameDialogListener.getTexts(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                      at com.example.anil.tictactoe.NameDialog$1.onClick(NameDialog.java:43)**
                      at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:175)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1518)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
```

Comment: post your activity code where you implemented this listener

Comment: I've added activity code which is implemented to the listener.

Answer (score 0):

1) From the question, it seems that the interface has not been properly implemented in the activity from which the Dialog is instantiated.

2) In case the interface has been properly implemented, you could try passing an instance of the activity in the constructor of the dialog like so

```
NameDialog(Activity activity){
     listener = (NameDialogListener) activity;
}
```

3) *(Not Recommended)* You can also try a quick fix *(Deprecated Method)* by overriding the **onAttach(Activity activity)** instead of the **onAttach(Context context)**. Basically the code would look like

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
       listener = (NameDialogListener) activity;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is deprecated.

Comment: I did mentioned it is a quick fix. If this works then we can go forward. The thing is i cannot comment in the question because you need 50 reputation to do that.

Comment: There is nothing called quick fix give the proper solution with proper explanation of  occurence of the  error.

Comment: @BennyHawk can you check my code again? I've added all classes.

Answer (score 0):

By referencing `listener` within an anonymous context, Java will create a final copy of the member to use within the anonymous class. This means that if the `listener` changes, the changes are not observed by the final copy.

In order to fix this, use a concrete class for the `OnClickListener` and pass the listener to it. This will avoid creating a final copy.

Comment: I don't think that's the case, as the field is an instance member, and therefore accessible without requiring to be final

Answer (score 0):

There must be an exception thrown try logging it or you can toast it or use debugger to see what's happening onDetach cannot be called before on onCreate

The context you are using is anonymous you should use a concrete one or cast it to where you are implementing the interface

Comment: Sorry I mean onAttach()

Comment: do listener = (NameDialogListener) getActivity(); but in onCreateDialog as you will get the activity context there and make sure to instantiate it before using it

Comment: Nothing changed! I've used this code in onAttach it didn't work. Also I've tried it in onCreateDialog, it didn't work again. I've added my all classes maybe you can give another solution.

Comment: sure just give the class where you have implemented the interface

Comment: I have already given the class where I have implemented the damn interface above.

Comment: You know what, you shouldn't comment here anymore, because you didn't read my question. If you read, you already will see that  I shared all code! Please do not write anything about my question anymore! I don't need your answer!

Comment: //In dialog
NameDialogListener nameDialogListener;
public void setCallbacks(NameDialogListener nameDialogListener){
        this.nameDialogListeners = nameDialogListener
    }

//Assuming your dialog instance
try doing this when you show the dialog
DialogObj obj =new DialogObj();
   obj.setCallbacks(this);      
   obj.show(getFragmentManager(), Constants.EMPTY_STRING);

Answer (score 0):

The problem might in the code showing the DialogFragment.
The good way to display DialogFrament is

> new NameDialog().show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"my_name_dialog");

This will invoke onAttach to get the context.

You should also change onAttach as below. Because of you don't need other using this DialogFragment to miss the implementation of the interface on your activity.

```
     @Override public void onAttach(Context context) {
         super.onAttach(context);
         if (context instanceof NameDialogListener) {
             mListener = (NameDialogListener) context;
         } else {
             throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                     + " must implement NameDialogListener");
         } 
     }
```